# Prevent opening office files in client

Tags: 2013, document-library, office-integration

I followed [instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/prevent-users-from-downloading-content-from-a-site-e17bf52b-fa5d-41cf-9eb0-d3812542424e) how to disable users of using offline client to view/edit documents. So they have to use web app mode.

I created dummy group of two users whom I gave contribute permissions. In library settings I set that documents are opened in web app by default. But as soon as docs are opened in web app they still can click on option **open in** and switch to client version of excel or word.

Did I miss something or should I add something else so users can't use clients?

Comment: In SP 2013 there is a menu in Doc Library settings > Advanced Settings > 'Opening Documents in the Browser'.  I'd be tempted to test the settings here and see if it helps.

Comment: I already did that. You can read it in second paragraph of my question, second sentence.

Comment: The wording is different in my menu.  Options I see are "Open in the client application"; "Open in the browser" or "Use the server default (Open in the browser)".  In any case, you've covered this already.